# How can I group array with a common value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly but I have an array of courses that I want to organize into columns based on activity titles. However, the activity titles (see array at bottom) are different but do have common attributes like Ceramics and Ceramics-Intermediate - these would go under one column titled Ceramics.
Desired result: (image)
[image: organized]

Currently, my foreach loop spits out a column for each course.

[image: each in own column]

```
<?php

$calendar = array();
foreach ($course as $row)
{
    $calendar[$row['CurrentCourse']['course_title']][] = $row;
}
?>
<div>
    <?php
    foreach($calendar as $key => $rows):
        ?>
        <div class="studio">
            <div class="column">
                <h2>
                    <?php
                    $mystudio = $key;
                    $flame = 'Flame';
                    $clay = 'Ceramics';
                    $metal = 'Jewelry';
                    $glass = 'Stained';
                    $wood = 'Wood';
                    if (strpos($mystudio, $flame) !== FALSE) {
                        echo "Flame Working";
                        $color = "pale-red";
                    }
                    elseif (strpos($mystudio, $clay) !== FALSE) {
                        echo "Ceramics";
                        $color = "pale-orange";
                    }
                    elseif (strpos($mystudio, $metal) !== FALSE) {
                        echo "Jewelry";
                        $color = "pale-yellow";
                    }
                    elseif (strpos($mystudio, $glass) !== FALSE) {
                        echo "Stained Glass";
                        $color = "pale-purple";
                    }
                    elseif (strpos($mystudio, $wood) !== FALSE) {
                        echo "Woodshop";
                        $color = "pale-tan";
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                    ?>
                </h2>
                <?php
                foreach($rows as $r):
                    ?>
                    <div class="time-slot <?php echo $color; ?>">
            <span class="title"><strong>
                    <?php echo $r["CurrentCourse"]["course_title"]; ?></strong></span>
            <span class="time">
                        <?php
                        $newST = strftime('%-I:%M %p', 
                            strtotime($r["CurrentCourse"]["course_start"]));
                        echo $newST;
                        ?>
                &nbsp;to&nbsp;
                <?php
                $newET = strftime('%-I:%M %p', 
                    strtotime($r["CurrentCourse"]["course_end"]));
                echo $newET;
                ?> 
                        </span>
                    </div><!-- end time slot -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!-- end div column -->
        </div><!-- end div studio -->
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div><!-- end div  -->
```

Below is a var_dump($row);

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "10:00:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-01-26 10:00:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) "Ceramics Class " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Beginning Ceramics, Wheel " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-03-01 12:00:00"["id"]=> string(4) "6577" } }
        array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "11:00:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-01-26 11:00:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) "Jewelry Smithing Class " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Jewelry Smithing " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-03-01 13:00:00" ["id"]=> string(4) "6655" } } 
        array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "11:00:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-01-26 11:00:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) "Jewelry Casting Class " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Jewelry Casting " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-03-01 13:00:00" ["id"]=> string(4) "6610" } } 
        array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-01-26 12:00:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) "Flame Working " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Beginning Flameworking " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-03-01 14:00:00"  ["id"]=> string(4) "6560" } } 
        array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "15:30:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-01-26 15:30:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) 
    "Flame Working Intermediate " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Intermediate Flameworking " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-03-01 17:30:00" ["id"]=> string(4) "6574" } } 
        array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["day_index"]=> string(1) "3" ["time"]=> string(8) "16:00:00" } 
        ["CurrentCourse"]=> array(6) { ["course_start"]=> string(19) "2016-04-12 16:00:00" ["daysofweek"]=> string(4) "Tue " ["activity_title"]=> string(60) "Ceramics-Intermediate " ["course_title"]=> string(60) "Intermediate Ceramics, Wheel " ["course_end"]=> string(19) "2016-05-17 18:00:00" ["id"]=> string(4) "6706" } }
```

Comment: From where it come your array? db query? json string? ...

Comment: Are you able to assign a category to the courses at the source? That would make the process much easier.

Comment: db query find all CurrentCourse where 'daysofweek'=Tue group by 'activity_title'

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't modify the source to include a category you may want to do that dynamically first and then use one of [these](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) functions to sort it.

Here's a quick sketch of that:

```
$categories =
     [
         "flame" => "pale-red",
         "ceramics" => "pale-orange",
     ];

foreach ($course as $row)
{
    $courseTitle = $row['CurrentCourse']['course_title'];        

    foreach ($categories as $cat)
    {
        if (stristr(strtolower($courseTitle), $cat) !== FALSE)
            $row['category'] = $categories[$cat];
    }

    // If no category has found add code here
    // to assign generic "unknown" category

    $calendar[$courseTitle][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting a create an array of categories that match the activity_title: $categories = array(
'flame working' => 'Flame Working',
'flame working intermediate' => 'Flame Working',
'ceramics class ' => 'Ceramics',
'ceramics-intermediate ' => 'Ceramics',
'bike repair' => 'Bike',
'bike maintenance' => 'Bike',
'jewelry smithing class' => 'Jewelry',
'jewelry casting class' => 'Jewelry'
);

Comment: the $categories = [ ]; is throwing me off, is that correct syntax? should ';' be commas?

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error, you are right, it should be commas and not semicolons - I've corrected it. What I'm suggesting is that you create an array of categories that either matches the activity_title or use something like `stristr()` to see if the category string is in the activity_title; in both cases allowing you to "tag" a row so that a sorting function could easily be used to group them after.

Comment: I've just updated the code to include the `stristr()` suggestion from above because it's probably closer to what you're looking for - "group by keyword in title" type match.

Comment: ok I'll keep trying but I do get syntax error with $categories = [

Comment: I'm not sure why, maybe you have an older version of PHP. Try doing `$categories = array(...)` instead.

Comment: yeah I've been trying that $categories = array(..); method but I get ["category"] = "NULL". Thanks for your help anyway.